# $X \subsetneq \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\partial X $ is an open set.

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a set $X \subsetneq \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\partial X $ is open set??

I know that if $X$ is open then $int(\partial X) = \emptyset$. So, the only way we get $int(\partial X) = \partial X$ is taking $X=\mathbb{R}^n$ (I guess the only open seth with boundary empty is $\mathbb{R}^n$).

So, if exists $X$ with that property then $X$ must not be  open.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For any subset $X$ of $\mathbb R^n$, $\partial X \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is closed. Indeed, recall that $\partial X = \overline X - int(X) = \overline X \cap (\mathbb R^n - int(X))$, which is an intersection of closed sets. Hence, $\mathbb R^n - \partial X$ is open. If we assume that $\partial X$ is open, then the disjoint union $\partial X \cup (\mathbb R^n - \partial X)$ is a disjoint union of open subsets of $\mathbb R^n$. The following is a fact of the topology of $\mathbb R^n$.

Let $U, V$ be disjoint open subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ such that $U \cap V = \mathbb R^n$. Then one of $U$ or $V$ must be empty.

We say therefore that $\mathbb R^n$ is *connected*. I won't prove this fact here - you can certainly find a reference somewhere on this site or elsewhere. Here's a hint though: any two points of $\mathbb R^n$ can be joined by a continuous path $[0, 1] \longrightarrow \mathbb R^n$.

Given the fact that $\mathbb R^n$ is connected, since $\partial X$ is both closed and open it must be $\emptyset$ or $\mathbb R^n$. The former is easy to achieve, take $X = \mathbb R^n$. The latter can be achieved as well, take $X = \mathbb Q^n$.